# I can not draw a gradient

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I write the following code:

```
CIFilter *Filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIRadialGradient"];

CIColor *startColor = [CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
CIColor *endColor = [CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
CIVector *startVector = [CIVector vectorWithX:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) Y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)];
NSNumber *radius1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:100];
NSNumber *radius2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1000];
[Filter setValue:startVector forKey:@"inputCenter"];
[Filter setValue:radius1 forKey:@"inputRadius0"];
[Filter setValue:radius2 forKey:@"inputRadius1"];
[Filter setValue:startColor forKey:@"inputColor0"];
[Filter setValue:endColor forKey:@"inputColor1"];

SKEffectNode *effectNode = [SKEffectNode node];
effectNode.filter = Filter;
effectNode.shouldEnableEffects = YES;

[self addChild:effectNode];
```

But on the screen, nothing happens. I use Sprite Kit.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it that way. According to Apple, the `filter` property of `SKEffectNode` needs and input and output image parameter:

> The Core Image filter must have a single inputImage parameter and
>   produce a single outputImage parameter.

This is not the case for `CIRadialGradient`, which has no `inputImage` parameter.

Comment: How do I draw a radial gradient on SKShapeNode?